# laravel 5.6 invoice manager - Call to a member function count() on string

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, invoice

i'm building a invoice manager app in laravel 5.6.
i'm tryiing to follow the following tut:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h6sTdAX6yTs&list=PLVAw_4sB6qJwCloLkV1SudLR0wcgiEXay&index=2
however i get stuck with on the part where i need to display invoices in the index (8:00).

Error:  Call to a member function count() on string

index.blade.php:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>Invoices</span>
            <a href="{{route('invoices.create')}}">Create</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @if(($invoices->count()))
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>invoice no.</th>
                    <th>Grand Total</th>
                    <th>Client</th>
                    <th>Invoice Date</th>
                    <th>Due Date</th>
                    <th colspan="2">Created At</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($invoices as $invoice)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$invoice->invoice_no}}</td>
                        <td>{{$invoice->grand_total}}</td>
                        <td>{{$invoice->client}}</td>
                        <td>{{$invoice->due_date}}</td>
                        <td>{{$invoice->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
            </table>
        @else
            <div>
                <p>
                    No Invoices were created.
                    <a href="{{route('invoices.create')}}">Create now!</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

InvoiceController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\InvoiceProduct;
use App\Invoice;
use DB;

class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $title = 'Welkom';
        //return view('pages.index', compact('title'));
        $invoices = DB::select('SELECT * FROM invoices');
        return view('invoices.index')->with('invoices', $title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the line causing the error? Can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: try this and let me know.use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 $invoices = DB::table('invoices')
            ->get();return view('invoices.index',compact('invoices','title'));

Comment: @NicoHaase The error is causing here:  if(($invoices->count())) in the index.blade.php

Comment: @SalmanZafar This worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: @JordinVanDelden pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use compact to pass variable from controller to view it's easier way.you can use any of the following code.

1st way using eloquent:

```
 public function index(){
        $title = 'Welkom';
        //return view('pages.index', compact('title'));
        $invoices = Invoice::all();
        return view('invoices.index',compact('title','invoices'));
    }
```

2nd way using query builder:

```
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; 

  public function index(){
        $title = 'Welkom';
        //return view('pages.index', compact('title'));
        $invoices = DB::select('SELECT * FROM invoices');
        return view('invoices.index',compact('title','invoices'));
    }
```

3rd way again using query builder:

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; 

 public function index(){
        $title = 'Welkom';
        //return view('pages.index', compact('title'));
        $invoices = DB::table('invoices')->get();
        return view('invoices.index',compact('title','invoices'));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`with`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Contracts/View/View.html#method_with) function accepts two parameters, a key and a value. In your case you have set the `"invoice"` key to the value of the string `$title`. If you want to include multiple parameters, you can use an associative array like so:

```
return view('invoices.index')->with([
    'invoices' => $invoices, 
    'title' => $title
]);
```

Even shorter is possible using the [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) function:

```
return view('invoices.index')->with(compact('invoices', 'title'));
```